# delete one out of multiple records from table

Tags: database, excel

I have data imported from an excel sheet into a table in db.
Now the data provided in excel sheet consists of multiple records having all except one column value different.
I need to delete one of the two.

Below is my sample data...
I need to delete the one with null in "variant" column

```
INDEX_NUM  ||  variant   || CASE_PACK   ||cases || units        
1020                         144               0       0        
1020           null          144               1       116     ------- >    TO DELETE 
1020            xyz          144               1       116
```

Data is the excel sheet itself is incorrect...It has multiple rows for same data just difference in variant.
I have got the data in my db.
Now i wan delete that row amongst the two havin variant as null
I cant use `HAVING COUNT(VARIANT) >1` as there are other rows which are currect, but which also have multiple variants.

So i need to ignore variants beginning with DP and BD.

I hope this is clear...

Comment: Which type of programming language, are you using?

Comment: "delete from table where variant is null"?

Comment: no programming language...need to migrate data from excel to db...

Comment: cant use delete as thr is another row with null n which is imp..
I need to delete only ones with all values same except variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE variant IS NULL
  AND index_num IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT index_num FROM your_table
     GROUP BY index_num, case_pack, cases, units
     HAVING COUNT(variant) > 1) p
```

Comment: above query doesnt do the needful :(

Comment: @Bhavna: pardon, what is the query you posted? Please edit your question and insert everything that could help us solving your trouble. More, you told us you have to delete some field from a database created importing Excel data... so, what do you really need?

Comment: @Bhavna: if you ask a question, answers are meant to solve that question (problem). If you need to ask other questions, create new questions on SO, don't ask inside first question. Now, did my ansewr provide a solution for the problem you originally asked?